# Get form contents from JQuery submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I am trying to get some form fields within a python script once the form has been submitted by a JQuery request. Here is the code I'm using:

Snippet.

```
<title>Line Chart</title>
            <script>
                    function clickme() {
                    drawgraph();
                    }
            </script>
            <script>
                    ajaxResponse = ".";
            </script>
            <script src="Chart.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script>
                    function drawgraph() {
                            function handleResponse(response) {
                                    ajaxResponse = response;
                            }
                            draw(handleResponse);
                    };

                    function draw(handleResponse) {
                            $.ajax({
                            url: "/currentcost.py",
                            data: $("form[name='frm']").serialize(),
                            success: function(response){
                                    handleResponse(response);
                            }
                            });
            }
            </script>
            <script>
                    function alertbox() {
                            alert(ajaxResponse);
                    }
            </script>
            <script>
```

My form, called frm, has two select boxes called dt and tm

The Python script called is:

```
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb
import os
fmeError: global name 'environ' is not defined
from cgi import parse_qs, escape

def index(req):

    # Returns a dictionary containing lists as values.
    d = parse_qs(os.environ['QUERY_STRING'])

    # In this idiom you must issue a list containing a default value.
    dtbox = d.get('dt', [''])[0] 
    tmbox = d.get('tm', [''])[0]
```

I'm expecting the variables `dtbox` and `tmbox` to contain the contents of the two form boxes dt and tm but in fact they are set to `None`

If I add a line into the JavaScript: `Type: "POST"`

The Python script bombs and an error is returned - "501 (Method Not Implemented)"

I know the script will work if these variables are returned as if I swap the comment tag over on the two select statements it works like a dream.

Please, someone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: what does $("form[name='frm']").serialize() return? could you post the rest of the code, maybe make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you post the form too?

Comment: @Fernando - I've edited the post and added more of the head section

Comment: @Nicolas, I've no idea how to tell! I thought all that did was to enable me to use the form.getvalue function in the currentcost.py script which is called when I click the Draw (submit) button on the form

Comment: can you do the python equivalent of PHP's print_r($_POST) ? in PHP, that will print the entire $_POST array (which is what serialize() will put all the form vars into).

Comment: @HC I'm sure there is a way but I've no idea what it is!

Comment: console.log($("form[name='frm']").serialize()) will output the value of the statement to the console. If you don't have a console available use alert($("form[name='frm']").serialize())

Comment: btw, if python errors out when you try to post to it, then you need to explicitly implement the post method (no idea how to do this though). Otherwise, if I understand correctly, you're performing a get operation on your script, and then trying to read you're values from the post body (unless cgi.FieldStorage() does something else). Perhaps you should read the querystring (where data is sent on an http get) instead of trying to read the post body. That would be consistent with what you're trying to do (a sql select is definitely a get). (you'd have build the url on the client)

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for your help. I have tried using query string but gave up as I couldn't get it to work! However, I'm trying again. I can see the URL is being constructed correctly but I still cannot get hold of the QUERY_STRING variable. I've edited my code above and when I run it I just get the message back "KeyError: 'QUERY_STRING'" HELP!! PLEASE

Comment: I want to see your HTML form. Does it have a `name=frm` ? Why don't you try to see your results using Chrome Console, for example, just like the guys are saying

Comment: @CHRISLEONARD, what is this line? `fmeError: global name 'environ' is not defined`